# How to send keyboard input only to a specific application

Tags: powershell, automation

I'm very new to Powershell. I wrote a simple script basically to automate grinding in a video game when I'm away from my computer. I wanted to know if there's a way instead to 'target' the button presses to a particular window/application/etc. while still working on the same machine in other windows. As it stands, I have to have the game window focused for the script to work so it's only really useful if I'm AFK. But if I could have it running in the background while working on other things that would be useful.

```
$WShell = New-Object -Com Wscript.Shell
while (1) {sleep 1; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{LEFT}"*80); 
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{RIGHT}"*80);sleep 1; 
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{C}"*20)}
```

Since I'm new to Powershell I'm not sure if this is doable or not. If not, it's no problem, this is a pretty frivolous use case, I was just curious.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what you're currently doing. . .it's almost the same as tying the shoe laces on a pair of shoes, just to put on different ones;) You're not using the `$wShell` anywhere in your script.

. . .but, you're almost there already. We can start by loading the required assemblies, and then have it point to the application which you want to interact with:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate('Notepad')
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("H")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("E")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("L")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("L")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("O")
```

Take note of *notepad* in `[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate('Notepad')`, as it will be what ever program you're trying to interact with.  In this case, you're just sending "HELLO" to the notepad that's *already* on started.

Comment: This is pretty close to what I'm looking for, but there's still the issue of keeping the keystrokes confined only to the application in 'AppActivate'. If I click out of that particular application and into another to work elsewhere, the keystrokes continue in the new application rather than the activated one. My hope is to have the app in AppActivate receive keystrokes in the background while I work in another window. This doesn't do that unfortunately. Is there something I could add in '[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("H")' to direct it only to the specific App?

Comment: Are the windows you're switching the same application?

Comment: No, they'd be things like Word, Chrome, etc. I only have one of the application I'd be sending keys to running at a time.

Comment: @Abraham Thanks for this! This gets me through a pseudo-silent install for a program that doesn't have built in silent parameters